# Scape data after login rvest

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

Please help me.
I'm trying to scrape the split table but actually I can't do and I don't understand why.
This is the url:
https://www.strava.com/activities/1983801964

This is the credential to login: 
email=trytest@tiscali.it
password=12345678

This is my code:

```
pgsession<-html_session("https://www.strava.com/login")

pgform<-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]  

filled_form<-set_values(pgform, email="trytest@tiscali.it", password="12345678")

submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)

page<-jump_to(pgsession, "https://www.strava.com/activities/1983801964")

page%>%html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="contents"]')
```

And I get {xml_nodeset (0)}

I tried everything, also

```
page%>%html_nodes("body")%>%html_text()
```

But I can't get this information, please help me!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find the split data in the HTML.  Therefore, it may not be possible to scrape the splits from the HTML like this.

Alternatively, you can download the raw activity data.  Link: https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/216918437-Exporting-your-Data-and-Bulk-Export

Edit: you may also be able to use this method to download Strava data: https://scottpdawson.com/export-strava-workout-data/

Edit 2: The splits are contained in a DIV called "splits-container".  But, the source HTML is likely modified by javascript after the page is loaded.  This means you will probably not be able to scrape the data without running the javascript first.  Hope this helps.